# How does a HTTP 1.0 only server respond to a HTTP 1.1 request?

Tags: http, version, backwards-compatibility

Fairly simple question (I think).  If a client sends a message like `GET /whatever HTTP/1.1` to a server that only supports HTTP 1.0, how does the server react?  What are the rules for header fields added in HTTP 1.1 that a HTTP 1.0 server doesn't recognise?  Does the server simply ignore 1.1 requests, ignore headers it doesn't understand, return an error, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

All headers of HTTP/1.1 (that a HTTP 1.0 server doesn't recognise) will be ignored.